# How to get count of rows from another tab to summary tab in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Excel (2021 version/google spreadsheet)

I am trying to grab count of non-blank/non-zero rows from 20 different tabs in excel and display the count in summary tab. The header of my summary tab looks like below:

> [image]

I am using =COUNTIF(G2:G22,"<>"&"No"&"") but this is working only in the current sheet. How do I use this in summary sheet?

What would be the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use the `ISBLANK(value)` operation? Where the `value` is the reference to the cell that will be checked for emptiness.

Reference:
[https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093290?hl=en#:~:text=ISBLANK%20returns%20TRUE%20if%20value,or%20a%20reference%20to%20data](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093290?hl=en#:%7E:text=ISBLANK%20returns%20TRUE%20if%20value,or%20a%20reference%20to%20data).

Comment: I am able to grab non-blank values. How do I get the count from another worksheet?

Comment: Use it like this in your function text box:
`=ISBLANK(worksheetName!cell)`

When writing the cell value, you can also just click the empty cell from the worksheet you want, and it will automatically set the value for you.

Hopefully it helped

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this by just putting the tab name.

```
=COUNTIF('CustomerServices'!G2:G22,"<>"&"No"&"")
```

Comment: `=COUNTIF('CustomerServices'!G2:G22,"<>No")`